# Ignore code analysis rules in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, code-analysis

How do I ignore a specific VS code analysis rule (say CA1305 : Microsoft.Globalization) within a:

- Method?
- Class?
- Namespace?

(Assuming these options are all possible.)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3683729/11410

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded FXCop as suggested by @TrueWill's comment on @AnthonyWJones' answer. This gave me the SuppressMessage:

```
[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Globalization",
    "CA1305:SpecifyIFormatProvider",
    MessageId = "System.String.Format(System.String,System.Object)")]
```

This was far harder than it should have been. What happened to that FXCop integration into Visual Studio? Thanks to the answerers for their help.

Comment: Thank you, how would I disable StyleCop warnings SA1307 and SA1305?

Comment: @Hamish: I don't know about StyleCop. You might need to ask a new question for that.

Comment: All right, I have done that. Just in case someone else will find this useful, here is a link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265154/how-to-disable-stylecop-warnings-sa1307-and-sa1305-around-a-struct

Answer (score 6):

You can use the SupressMessage attribute like this:-

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2233:OperationsShouldNotOverflow", MessageId = "newValue+1", Justification = "The reason I think its acceptable in this case")]
void SomeMethod()
{
   // Some code that would normal cause this Code Analysis message
}
```

On a method, property, type etc.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I tried `[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA1305:Microsoft.Globalization")]` (for brevity) on a method but still the warning showed. Any ideas?

Comment: @Alex: Try changing the category to "Microsoft.Globalization", see:-
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182190.aspx

Comment: You could try running FxCop, right-clicking the errors, and choosing Copy As SuppressMessage. That should get you the right attribute text.

Comment: Note that you have to compile with the CODE_ANALYSIS conditional then.

Answer (score 1):

Use `#pragma warning(suppress: Cxxxx)`

You can put the pragma at the appropriate scope in the source file (i.e. class, method)

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(VS.80).aspx

Comment: #pragma warning works for compiler warnings. Does it also work for code analysis?

Comment: @OregonGhost #pragma warning(suppress) was introduced specifically for TFS code analysis.

Comment: @JaredPar The question doesn't mention FxCop?

Comment: @Stu it says Code Analysis warnings and mentions a specific category by name (Microsoft.Globalization)

Comment: @Stu: I've tried this with `#pragma warning(suppress: CA1305)` and no success. Ideas?

Comment: From the docs: "suppress is only supported for C6000 warnings (code analysis warnings), which are enabled with the /analyze (Enterprise Code Analysis) compiler option." You could use #pragme warning(disable) instead, or alternatively use the SuppressMessage attribute as @AnthonyWJones suggests.

Comment: Also:

If the #pragma warning directive with the suppress warning specifier does not suppress the warning, it might be because the particular warning applies to the function body as a whole, not its individual statements. To suppress warnings of this type, such as Warning 28195, place the #pragma warning directive on the line immediately preceding the first brace ({) of the function body.