# How do I suppress FxCop rule 'DoNotCatchGeneralExceptionTypes' with SupressMessage?

Tags: fxcop

I've got code that catches everything and logs it.  I don't normally do this, but I'm writing an HTTP handler and want to return an appropriate HTTP code.  Anyway,  I'm putting the following at the top of my method:

`[SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1031:DoNotCatchGeneralExceptionTypes", Justification = "We just log the exception and return an HTTP code")]`

FxCop is seemingly ignoring this, which is very frustrating.  Especially as it's also ignoring all of my compound word overrides too!

Any idea why it's doing this?  I'm using FxCop 10 which is part of the Windows 7/.NET 4 SDK.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> 1. In **Solution Explorer**, right-click your project and choose
>      **Properties**.
> 2. In the **Properties** window, choose the **Build** tab.
> 3. In the **Conditional compilation symbols** text box, enter
>      **CODE_ANALYSIS**.
> 4. In the code where you want to suppress certain messages, add the
>      namespace
>      **System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis** to the using section.
> 5. In FxCop, right-click the message you want to suppress and
>      select **Copy As -> SuppressMessage**.
> 6. In your C# code, paste the SuppressMessage attribute in your
>      code.

Your SupressMessage looks correct, so it could be the missing conditional compilation symbol!

Hope this helps, at least works on my machine ;)
Greetz, Tom.

[Source](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/jschreuder/archive/2006/06/08/12400.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Tom, this isn't the first time I've forgotten that symbol! :|